# Convert BCD byte array to a NSDecimalNumber

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, bcd, tlv

Given a 6 byte array from a specific TLV tag:

```
unsigned char bytes[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45 };
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:6];
```

How could one convert it to the decimal number with value of:

```
12345
```

I tried finding something that is already implemented in Foundation, but with no luck.

Comment: The result doesn't seem to be related to the byte array (3 vs 6 digits, different order)

Comment: I updated the question with nicer example. This encoding is used for `9F02` tlv tag to represent decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Step 1: convert data to string
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:data.length];
unsigned char *bytes = [data bytes];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [data length]; i++)
    [string appendFormat:@"%.2x", bytes[i]];

// Step 2: convert string to decimal number
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply mul and add:

```
int sum = 0;
for( int c = 0; c<6 c++ )
{
  sum *= 100; // shift up two decimal digits
  sum += bytes[c] & 0xF + 10 * bytes[c] >> 4; // add new digits
}
NSNumber *result = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sum];
```

Typed in Safari.